# iOS: Checking String Prefix Using Switch Case?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, switch-statement, range

I'm currently trying to look at the first two characters of a string, and depending on what they are, I want to do something. There are 6 possibilities: AA, BB, CC, AB, BC, CA.

I tried the following but kept getting the following error:

[image]

```
NSString *housing = [myArray firstObject];
    switch([housing compare:housing options:@"AA", @"BB", @"CC", @"AB", @"BC", @"CA" range:2]) {

        case 0:
            break;

        case 1:
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        case 5:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: What's the warning say?

Comment: But generally, I think you're using the compare method wrong… Going to double check before answering...

Comment: Updated my answer to include the error. It's asking for an expected ":" at range. I agree, I'm pretty sure this is completely wrong. I guess what I'm asking is what's the best way to go about this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

(1) The `NSString` immediately before `compare` and the `NSString` immediately after `compare` are the strings you are comparing to one another, so to compare "housing" to "housing" doesn't make sense.

(2) You're misusing `options`. `options` only accepts the following *search* options -- NSCaseInsensitiveSearch, NSLiteralSearch, NSNumericSearch.

(3) And range needs to be an NSRange, not just a number.

[Here's the class reference.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-compare_options_range_)

Edit: Just thought up a pretty elegant solution, if I don't say so myself… (It's 3 AM here though, so you should double check the logic to make sure I'm not delirious.)

```
// Check to see if the first 2 characters of the housing string are in an array of the characters
switch([[@"AA", @"BB", @"CC", @"AB", @"BC", @"CA"] indexOfObject:[housing substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]){

    case 0: // Do something if first 2 characters are AA
    break;

    case 1: // Do something if first 2 characters are BB
    break;

    // etc ...

    default: // Do something if not found
    break;
}
```